# Is possible to use $.get via browser console

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, console

I'm trying to call an ajax request using Chrome console, somehow when I'm typing `console.log()` or `alert()` it's working, but when I'm trying to use jQuery `$.get` or `$.ajax` it just seems to console.log whole jQuert function/object but it's not calling it at all.

code is realy simple:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://www.my_server.com/controler',
   data: 'test',
   type: 'GET'
});
```

Is it possible to use `$.get` or `$.ajax` from console?

Comment: only if JQuery is loaded on the page on which you are using the console.

Comment: I quess It is loaded otherwise it should return something like 'undefined is not a function' but it's returning jQuery.ajax object

Comment: inspect request in network tab otherwise there is generally no problem doing this so long as not running into cross domain issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is the expected behaviour. `$.ajax` returns a [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) object. If you're interested in the response, then provide a `success` callback and log the results there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.get` or `$.ajax` in Chrome console, but you can't display it this way (I mean by using `console.log`). What you can do is using `$.ajax` callback function to display it, or you can assign the response data to a variable and use `console.log` to display it.

Comment: I did use `succes: function(data){console.log(data)}` to see the response but somehow It's console.log whole jqXHR anyway

Comment: Can you tell me what are you typing in Chrome console please?

Comment: exactly that what is in code section in my question

Comment: Ok I see, you can console.log the data at success callback like this: success: function(data) { console.log(data) }   and it will still show you as the object, but you will be able to see the response. The reason is that $.ajax call returns object, and you can't work it around. I hope this is helpful...